# loading Windows executable - unexpected data appended to sections after loading in memory

Tags: reverse-engineering, disassembly

I'm trying to write a program analysing Windows executables. I was assuming that sections in executable file are directly mapped to memory. I have noticed strange behaviour in several programs. One example is crackme12.exe . When I check with debugger .rdata section loaded into memory I can see that for some reason 96 bytes have been added at the beginning of a section loaded into memory that was not there in the executable file. I have spent 2 days trying to read Windows executable documentation, but I can't find explanation why is it happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One explanation might be that the program itself has put a stream in the memory section, this is not unusual. You will not find this kind of explanation in the [Portable Executable Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx). Some (malware) executables also replace or add new sections. Other (obfuscated) executables will expand existing empty file sections to non-empty memory sections.